# python CQL query substitution for "select * from CF where column in (..,..,..)"

Tags: python, cassandra, cql

Here is my column family definition:

```
CREATE TABLE columnfamily (column1 int PRIMARY KEY, column2 text);
```

I am using python cassandra-dbapi2 1.4.0 to connect to Cassandra 1.1.6, using CQL 3 syntax. I would like to use query substitution on the following query, but it seems not working at WHERE... IN (...,...):

```
cql = "SELECT * FROM columnfamily WHERE column1 IN (:x) and column2 = :y;"
q = cursor.prepare_query(cql)

cursor.execute_prepared(q, {'x':(1,2,3), 'y':'abc'}
```

I got the following error after trying the above:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_cassandra.py", line 17, in <module>
    cursor.execute_prepared(q, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cql/cursor.py", line 89, in execute_prepared
    response = self.get_response_prepared(prepared_query, params, cl)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cql/thrifteries.py", line 83, in get_response_prepared
    paramvals = prepared_query.encode_params(params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cql/query.py", line 60, in encode_params
    return [t.to_binary(t.validate(params[n])) for (n, t) in zip(self.paramnames, self.vartypes)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cql/cqltypes.py", line 225, in to_binary
    return cls.serialize(val)
struct.error: cannot convert argument to integer
```

I have also tried to use the following:

```
cursor.execute_prepared(q, {'x':','.join([str(i) for i in (1,2,3)]), 'y':'abc'}
```

Same error happened. Does anyone know what would be the correct way to do query substitution inside WHERE ... IN (...,...) statement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Cassandra is the piece interpolating bound values on a prepared query, here, and it does not support binding a sequence of values, so the answer is pretty much, "you can't do that (yet)".

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4210 if you want to keep an eye on the situation there.

It *would* be possible to support this sort of structure in the python-cql driver in the plain `execute()` call, wherein the query interpolation is done on the Python side, but you wouldn't get any of the benefits of prepared queries, and it wouldn't be much more than just

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM a WHERE b IN (%s)'
               % ', '.join(map(cql.query.cql_quote, your_list_of_values)))
```